# Retaining blank rows while comparing data in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I seem to be in a stump right now and any help would be appreciated.

I have a spread sheet with a bunch of data. Basically, one column of data has multiple names. Each name is associated with an `act #`. Account Allan may appear `4 times` because there are `4 accounts` for him.

I need to pull that ONE Allan out and his account #'s into a new column and have the account numbers read across in the row. The file has all account #'s in one column. Which is an issue.

I've managed to complete the first task. Currently what happens is I'll drag down the cell where my formula is and it will in fact only generate ONE copy of the persons name and in the next cell over I have the account numbers splitting as they should in a row now. My only issue is that even thought its pulling just ONE person it's not inserting a blank row where the duplicates would be.

I apparently can't add images considering this is my first post or something so here are the 2 formulas I've used for this so far:

`=INDEX($B$2:$B$50, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($L$1:$L1, $B$2:$B$50), 0))`

`=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$50, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($L2:L2,$C$2:$C$50)+IF($B$2:$B$50<>$L2, 1, 0), 0)), 0)`

The first formula is the one that pulls just one of the persons name if it finds a duplicate and the other formula is the one where it pulls the multiple account numbers if any for that person into a row.

[image]

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwSwZ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmnF.png

Comment: "Note the formula in cell L2" Did you mean to attach an image? I don't see anything.

Comment: Updated it a bit.

Comment: It would help to include a screenshot of some sample data.

Comment: It won't let me post any until I get 10 points or something :/

Comment: Can you upload to Imgur or create a table in your question? It's still not very clear. What is in column B, C, and L?

Comment: are you trying to clear data in rows ?

Comment: added image links

Comment: @ARain After rereading your description, I think you want a pivot chart. Place `Name` as a row and `Account #` as a column. This should give you one person and all their accounts together.

Comment: Thanks guys/girls? haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-index-match and matching your columns:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$50,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$50=$D2,ROW($B$2:$B$50)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:$B$50,1,1))+1),M$1)),0)
```

Enter it in the first cell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and then copy the cell over all other cells. This is based on that the column-header has the value 1,2,3,4,5 etc for which nth of the accountnumber. You could refine it to match your headers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late for the reply but thank you so much for everyones input especially yours KeshShan! I did end up getting everything to work.

I did use the index match and a couple "IF" statements, see below. Thank you!!

```
=IF($D2<>"",INDEX($B$2:$B$50, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($L$1:$L1, $B$2:$B$50), 0)),"")

=IF((IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$50, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($L2:L2,$C$2:$C$50)+IF($B$2:$B$50<>$L2, 1, 0), 0)), 0))=0,"",(IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$50, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($L2:L2,$C$2:$C$50)+IF($B$2:$B$50<>$L2, 1, 0), 0)), 0)))

=IF(B2="","",IF(COUNTIF($B2:B34026,B2)=1,B2,""))
```

Funny thing is, the new issue this project has presented is that it takes absolutely way too long to actually process all of these formulas for over 30 thousand records.

I need to learn more about SQL I heard? I'm hoping to become a Data Analyst one day, get back into school soon to learn more about data (I never thought those words would ever come out of my mouth haha) I actually find it fun and interesting now! I'm currently self taught so I apologize for so many weird questions! Any direct messages about SQL and where I should start would be awesome! Thank you!

Here are the results of these formulas. By looking at these 3 pictures it should be clear to see what I was trying to accomplish. Just needed to split the data in coloumn B & C into seperate rows for a data merge onto a letter.
[One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPpFc.jpg)
[Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hYzQ.jpg)
(See next comment for third picture)